# Prevent user to click anywhere on page if changed value is not submitted

Tags: javascript, angular, preventdefault, stoppropagation

in my app, the user has multiple inputs, and I use `@hostListener` for click outside, because I have some complicated inputs (multiple checkboxes where I first need to check everything and after call submits on click outside, IMG-MAP, etc....).

```
--- TEXT INPUT ---
 *add some value...*
    -> click outside -> Submit


--- RADIO BUTTON ---
 *change option...*
    -> click outside -> Submit

...etc
```

how to in angular 9+ prevent users to click anywhere (menu, another input ...)? If the user change the value and click anywhere or on any other part of the app ( any button, menu item, another input) `submit` method for changed input needs to be executed instead of that where he clicked.

I try to add `event.PreventDefault()`, but if we click on the menu or on another button it is not triggered `submit for changed value`, it is a triggered method for clicked item (menu item...).

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickOut(event) {
event.preventDefault();   // if change val in text input and click directlly on radio button option, radio button option i changed and trigered submit for text input, and that is not ok, option in radio butoon can't be changed
  this.submit() 
  }
```

Comment: You need to layer a transparent <div> between the form and the rest of the page.

Comment: @ChrisG thnx, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Yeah, kind of, you'll need a bunch of CSS, that's for sure. How to approach this best also depends heavily on the current layout of your page. For instance if your users are fine with the form basically being a popover, you can simply wrap it in a div positioned fixed at 0,0 with a height of 100vh.

Comment: Thnx for the idea, I will try something that way. If you, maybe, have any example it will be great.

Comment: Here's a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/ah6evzxL/

Answer (score 0):

why not use `(blur)`?

Another idea can be get the `event.target as HTMLElement;` and check if is inner to your form to not execute event.PreventDefault()

```
@ViewChild('myForm',{read:ElementRef}) formElement:ElementRef
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickOut(event) {
     const clickTarget = event.target as HTMLElement;
     if (this.formElement.nativeElement.contains(clickTarget))
     {
        console("inside myForm")
     }
     else
     {
        console("outside myForm")
     }
  }
```

NOTE: I don't check the code (I'm in hurry), but I imagine work